# Can I make Windows 10 leave my USB drives alone?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, usb-storage, mirroring, storage-spaces

**TLDR: please name anything I can modify or disable to minimize access to my USB drives when I am not actively using them**

I have two USB3.0 drives in a two way mirror storage space. They are also shared in the local network. 
Now whenever they're not needed they turn off which is wanted behavior. But Windows seems to wake the drives up (sometimes one sometimes both) at random times of the day. I tried monitoring it with procmon.exe and it seems like windows explorer is creating and accessing security files like every 5 minutes. But that doesn't seem to wake them up. But every now and then svchost.exe seems to go very deep into random directories and tries to create and access some files for no apparent reason I am not sure if it's the sole process responsible for the waking up but I saw at least one instance where they woke up and svchost was doing this. I think sometimes this kind of access didn't wake them up though. I'm not exactly sure as I have to be there to see it happen.

Now is there anything I can do to minimize Windows accessing those drives when idle? I did already disable indexing. What services and other features could also be responsible?
And a bonus question: When rebooting apparently Windows has to wait for the drives to wake up to do whatever with them before it can actually shut down. Then while posting they turn off again only to be woken up again and windows waiting for that before it can finish booting. Can I change this behavior? Can I tell windows to not check all drives when shutting down or starting up?

Comment: Yes I did. I mentioned that in the last paragraph. It didn't really seem to reduce the access frequency sadly

Comment: Also look at Storage Spaces as that may be accessing your drive. Google for this and you see lots of people experiencing the same thing so it may not be something you can readily control.   https://www.groovypost.com/howto/view-all-connected-storage-devices-on-windows-10-1903/

Comment: Make the drives offline when not in use

Comment: @John I was considering this as well and of course it might be due to it being a storage space and als due to it being a network drive that maybe some routines need to check if it's still there every now and then. But I want to reduce these occurences as much as possible. Maybe there is some stuff that is unnecessary and can be prevented through tweaking some settings.

Comment: @Madhubala that kinda defeats the purpose of my whole setup. The drives are supposed to be available on the network I just don't want them running when they're not needed. And not have them turn on unnecessarily